# Building MongoDB C++ driver on Windows

Tags: c++, mongodb

Reading the manual.
http://mongocxx.org/mongocxx-v3/installation/
There is
**Step 2: Choose a C++17 polyfill**
...
*Boost (default for Windows platforms) Select with -DBSONCXX_POLY_USE_BOOST=1. This is currently the only option if you are using MSVC.*
...
**I cannot understand what I have to do.**
And, as a result if we go to Step3 and try to build we get an error:
-- Auto-configuring bsoncxx to use boost std library polyfills since C++17 is inactive and compiler is MSVC

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2132 (message):  
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Unable to find the Boost header files.  Please set BOOST_ROOT to the root
  directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory containing
  Boost's headers.
```

Comment: What version of MSVC are you using?

Comment: 2017 community edition

Comment: Can you require C++17? More specifically, is C++17 allowed in the project where you want to consume the driver.

Comment: As I can understand from the documentation, __This is currently the only option if you are using MSVC.__ I just cannot understand what I have to do to switch on -DBSONCXX_POLY_USE_BOOST=1

Comment: There may be other options if you can use depend on C++17 features. Notably, you can use *no polyfill at all*. So, my question stands: Is mandating the use of C++17 OK in the context of the consumers of the driver?

Answer (score 0):

You still need to install the boost libraries, for example get boost here: https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_71_0.html

Then add the boost path when you try to build as stated in the error, e.g.

```
C:\mongo-cxx-driver>cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\mongo-cxx-driver
    -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\mongo-c-driver
    -DBSONCXX_POLY_USE_BOOST=1
    -DBOOST_ROOT=C:\boost\boost_1_71_0
```